# In which order should I load inputenc and fontenc?

Tags: pdftex, packages, incompatibility, font-encodings, input-encodings

When I’m using pdfLaTeX, my preamble usually contains

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

**Should these two be loaded in any particular order?** What problems could arise if they’re loaded in the “wrong” order?

On a related topic, I know that `fontenc` should come *after* font packages, as described in [Should the fontenc package be loaded before or after font packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2859/should-the-fontenc-package-be-loaded-before-or-after-font-packages), so I’d move font packages along with `inputenc` – unless there’s a catch as well, which would indicate something like
1) font package(s) 2) `inputenc` 3) `fontenc`?

Answer (score 12):

No the order doesn't matter as `inputenc` contains some code to avoid "order problems".

Some background: `inputenc` with option utf8 doesn't set up definitions for every unicode character as everyone knows who got once the message `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:... not set up for use with LaTeX.`

Instead it loads a `.dfu` for each font encoding declared by `fontenc` (naturally only if the `dfu` exists) so that there exist input definitions for the chars that can be printed with this font encodings.

`fontenc` puts all the font encodings it has been called with or which have been loaded by default in a list `\cdp@list`. `inputenc` process this list and loads the corresponding `.dfu` (e.g. `T1.dfu`) and then redefines `\DeclareFontEncoding@` so that from now on every `\DeclareFontEncoding` will load the `.dfu` directly.

Comment: In [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241479/), David Carlisle says that `fontenc` should be loaded before `inputenc`. Is that incorrect or has the situation changed since you wrote this?