# Integration with textstyle fractions limits

Tags: displaystyle

I am trying to write an integration question like below with amsmath package:

```
\displaystyle\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x
```

However, the two fractions limits appear to be too small. I would like to do something like this:

```
\displaystyle\int_{\textstyle\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\textstyle\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x
```

Is there an efficient way to set all the integration limits in the document to \textstyle?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't do that. By the way, a full compilable example would be welcome (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) so it allows us to just copy your code to start working rather than writing it ourselves ;)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could use `\tfrac`, provided you have `\usepackage{amsmath}`; but the best is to use the slashed form: `\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}`

Comment: In fact, Dexter wong, I think you *do* want to use `\tfrac` in case, if you set all the sub/superscripts in textstyle `\int_0^1 f` would be definetly ugly with `0` and `1` of the same height of `f`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your great comments. I will use \tfrac in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The only sensible way is to use `\tfrac`. Note the inconsistency in a common situation either with default or using `\textstyle`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}

    Default:
    \[  \int_{k\frac{\pi}{4}}^{k\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x \]%
    \vskip 2ex
    With \verb+\tfrac+:
      \[ \int_{k\tfrac{\pi}{4}}^{k \tfrac{\pi}{2}}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x  \]%
    \vskip 2ex
    With \verb+\textstyle+:
    \[  \int_{\textstyle k\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\textstyle  k\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x \]%

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And here I'm again (I will delete this shortly). Since you add `inputenc` and `fontenc` to your answers… I think I've read somewhere that it's better to load `fontenc` first.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34046/21930) and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97318/21930), although I might not understood correctly the second one because in the same answers it states that the order doesn''t matter (while the explanation, in my opinion, proves it otherwise) :D

Answer (score 1):

You asked,

> Is there an efficient way to set all the integration limits in the document to `\textstyle`?

When TeX is in displaymath mode, `\int` produces a "large" integral symbol and the upper and lower limits of integration are typeset in `scriptstyle`. What you're encountering is that the numerators and denominators inside these limits are typeset in `scriptscriptstyle` if `\frac` is used.

To change this default behavior globally, i.e., to switch from `scriptstyle` to `textstyle` in the limits of integration on a document-wide basis, would require major surgery on TeX's math innards and is not to be undertaken lightly. And I would hate to call such coding efficient. Moreover, you will probably not like the resulting look if the limits contain simple numbers and letters (since these will now be set in `textstyle`, i.e., the same size as applies for `\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x`.

You could use `\tfrac` explicitly -- `\tfrac` is short for `\textstyle\frac`-- to get scriptsize- rather than scriptscriptsize-sized numerator and denominator terms; the resulting look is also shown in @Bernard's earlier answer. Alternatively, you could use "inline-style" fraction notation, i.e., write `\pi/4` and `\pi/2` in the limits; these terms will be set in scriptstyle automatically.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \text and \tfrac macros
\begin{document}
\[
\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x    % \frac
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\int_{\tfrac{\pi}{4}}^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x  % \tfrac
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x                    % inline-style
\]
\end{document}
```