# Generating a template

Tags: errors, templates

My professor gave me a template which I compiled but it gave me lots of errors.

The code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{rotating,graphics,psfrag,epsfig}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\newcommand{\ff}{Marzo del 2007}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

%\usepackage[thickspace]{SIunits}

\usepackage[a]{esvect}
\usepackage{shortlst}

\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\newcommand{\solucion}{\noindent\textbf{Soluci\'on}}
\newcommand{\comentario}{\noindent\textbf{Comentario}}
\newcommand{\nota}{\noindent\textbf{Nota}:}
\newcommand{\suge}{\noindent\textbf{Sugerencia}:}
\newcommand{\analisis}{\noindent\textbf{An\'alisis}}
\newcommand{\modelo}{\noindent\textbf{Modelo}}


\fancyhead[L]{} 
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{} 
%
\fancyfoot[L]{http://fisica.usach.cl/$\sim$cesparza/}
%\fancyfoot[C]{\ff} 
\fancyfoot[C]{} 
\fancyfoot[R]{TeoIngMat-EXA1s11.pdf -- 15 noviembre 2011}

\headwidth 18.0cm
\textwidth 18.0cm %18.0cm
\textheight 25.00cm % era25
\oddsidemargin -0.8cm
\evensidemargin -0.8cm
\topmargin -3.5000cm %era  -2.0cm
\columnsep 0.3cm
\parindent 0pt

\newcommand{\ia}{\'{\i}}
\newcommand{\xu}{\rm {\widehat{\bf{x}}}}
\newcommand{\yu}{\rm {\widehat{\bf{y}}}}
\newcommand{\zu}{\rm {\widehat{\bf{z}}}}

\newcommand{\iu}{\mathbf{\hat{\imath}}}
\newcommand{\ju}{\mathbf{\hat{\jmath}}}
\newcommand{\ku}{\mathbf{\hat{\kappa}}}
\newcommand{\kuw}{\mathbf{\widehat{\kappa}}}



\usepackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{ 
pdfauthor = Carlos Esparza Barrera, 
pdftitle = TeoF1-IngMat-EXA1s11.pdf, 
pdfsubject = 2red, 
pdfkeywords =carlos.esparza@usach.cl, 
pdfcreator = {LaTeX con la paqueteria hyperref }, 
pdfproducer = {dvpdfm} 
}



\usepackage{type1cm} 
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{color} 

\begin{document}

 \psfrag{xu}{$\widehat{\bf{x}}$}
 \psfrag{yu}{$\widehat{\bf{y}}$}
\psfrag{iu}{$\mathbf{\hat \imath}$}
 \psfrag{ju}{$\mathbf{\hat \jmath}$} 
 \psfrag{i}{$\hat \imath$}
 \psfrag{j}{$\hat \jmath$}

\textbf{Departamento de Fisica \hfill Universidad de Santiago de Chile} 

Teoria a Física I (22104)\hfill \textbf{EXAMEN} \hfill Ingeniería Matemática  \vspace{0.1cm}

\hline \hline \vspace{0.2cm}

Prof. Carlos H. Esparza-Barrera \hfill \begin{LARGE} \raisebox{-0.5ex}{\Email}                               
           \end{LARGE}  ~carlos.esparza@usach.cl \hfill \begin{LARGE}\Telefon \end{LARGE} ~(56-2-)7181239
\hfill Oficina 27 \\[0.1cm] 

\hline
\begin{itemize}

\item  \begin{large} \textbf{Esta prueba
consta de cuatro problemas, usted debe responder tres de ellos. La
elección es suya y debe indicarla en la hoja. Si responde los cuatro, se considerarán los tres
peor evaluados}\end{large}.  \hfill  Cada problema vale $2,0$ puntos. 

\item Fundamente su razonamiento; haga esquemas explicatorios. Use
l\'apiz  indeleble; en caso contrario, no puede pretender una segunda revisi\'on de su trabajo. Exprese sus
repuestas numéricas con 3 CS.


\item Las situaciones y los valores num\'ericos de los datos suministrados no necesariamente corresponden a
los de un experimento o situaci\'on pr\'actica real.  Se pretende que usted  trabaje cada problema  con
el modelo adecuado en el marco de la  teor\'ia  pertinente y obtenga las predicciones correspondientes. 

\end{itemize}
\hline

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}


\item problema 1

\item ...

\item ...


\item ...


\item ...


\item ...
\end{enumerate}
```

Compiling in Latex=>PS=>PDF, I have the following errors:

Misplaced \noalign x4 and Emergency stop.

I don't know how to fix this.

The result should be the following:

[image]

After the last horizontal line, I edited the problems so there's no text in there as you can see in the code.

I had to repost this because I messed up in the other thread.
I appreciate the help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. You can simply edit your original posting.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in these forums. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: The template uses `dvpdfm` option on several packages so it is not for latex-ps-pdf or for pdflatex but for latex-dvi-pdf via dvipdfm, as such psfrag package shouldn't be loaded. epsfig package should _never_ be loaded, you load `marvosym` twice, you shouldn't use `\bf` or `\rm`, especially in math mode...

Comment: You mean I can't compile in LaTeX=>PS=>PDF? How can I do it to compile with that profile?

Comment: the error message about `\noalign` is from `\hline` which can only be used inside `tabular` simply delete it,.

Comment: @Oshnaj the profile isn't consistent, it uses `psfrag` that relies on postscript and it specifies `dvipdfm` which does not use postscript,  it also uses obsolete package such as `epsfig` obsolete macros such as `\rm` and local packages which mean that we can not test it properly here.  ( `shortlst.sty`)

Comment: This seems to be the code that initiated writing `l2tabu`. Most of the code is obsolete by now, starting from scratch would be much faster than starting to fix and hack.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, starting from scratch is much better! This is a reason why I put my answer where whole document is rewritten to plain TeX.

Comment: @Oshnaj Can you change the title of the question? It is somehow misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example more in the spirit of LaTeX, as I see it. (Not to compete with the other answers but to demonstrate the benefits of the LateX approach, for those who see it as beneficial).

If you needed to produce many such documents, you could design a custom preamble (or package) along these lines. This completely separates presentation from style, so that the markup inside the `document` environment is completely semantic. And I think it also uses fairly simple solutions to achieve the desired layout style.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{marvosym} % for icons
\usepackage{url} % for e-mail address
\usepackage{sectsty}  % for customizing section font

\sectionfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

% Horizontal rule
\newlength{\normalrulethickness}
\setlength{\normalrulethickness}{0.4pt}
\newcommand{\thinrule}{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{\normalrulethickness}}
\newcommand{\thickrule}{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{2\normalrulethickness}}
\newcommand{\doublerule}{%
    \thickrule%
    \llap{\rule[2pt]{\linewidth}{\normalrulethickness}}%
}
% Letterhead at top of page
\newcommand{\letterhead}{%
    \noindent%
    \textbf{\department}\hfill \textbf{\university}\newline
    \course\hfill \documentname\hfill \subject\newline
    \doublerule\par\smallskip
    {\small\noindent%
    \professor\hfill \emailicon\ \email\hfill \phoneicon\ \phone\hfill \office%
    }\par\bigskip%
}

% Commands to set the values in the \letterhead
\newcommand{\setdepartment}[1]{\gdef\department{#1}}
\newcommand{\setuniversity}[1]{\gdef\university{#1}}
\newcommand{\setcourse}[1]{\gdef\course{#1}}
\newcommand{\setsubject}[1]{\gdef\subject{#1}}
\newcommand{\setdocumentname}[1]{\gdef\documentname{#1}}
\newcommand{\setprofessor}[1]{\gdef\professor{#1}}
\newcommand{\setemail}[1]{\gdef\email{\url{#1}}}
\newcommand{\setphone}[1]{\gdef\phone{#1}}
\newcommand{\setoffice}[1]{\gdef\office{#1}}

% Icons in letterhead
\newcommand{\emailicon}{\Email} % from marvosym
\newcommand{\phoneicon}{\Telefon}


% Block of instructions with rule before and after
\newenvironment{instructions}{\thickrule}{\thickrule}

% 2-column exam questions
\newenvironment{examquestions}
    {\begin{multicols}{2}}
    {\end{multicols}}

\newcommand{\pointvalue}[1]{\hfill\mbox{#1}}
\newcommand{\strong}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\setdepartment{Departamento de Física}
\setuniversity{Universidad de Santiago de Chile}
\setcourse{Teoría Física (22104)}
\setsubject{Ingeniería Matemática}
\setdocumentname{EXAMEN}
\setprofessor{Prof.~Carlos H.~Esparza-Barrera}
\setemail{carlos.esparza@usach.cl}
\setphone{(56-2-)7181239}
\setoffice{Oficina 27}

\letterhead

\begin{instructions}
\begin{itemize}
\item \strong{%
Esta prueba consta de cuatro problemas, usted debe responder tres de ellos.
La elección es suya y debe indicarla en la hoja. 
Si responde los cuatro, se considerarán los tres peor evaluados.
}\pointvalue{Cada problema vale $2,0$ puntos.}
\item Fundamente su razonamiento; haga esquemas explicatorios. [\dots]
\item Las situaciones y los valores numéricos de los datos suministrados [\dots]
\end{itemize}
\end{instructions}

\begin{examquestions}

\section{Insectos}
Algunos coleópteros pueden proyectarse verticalmente [\dots]

\section{Esferas de aluminio y fierro}
La masa de un metro cúbio de Al es $2,70 \times 10^3$~kg [\dots] %better to use siunitx 

\end{examquestions}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should add, that reusing this stuff would mean *hiding* most of the definitions in a wrapper class/package.  Since this is a physics topic, maybe package `siunitx` comes in handy. There might be a lot more units in the text we don't see. :-)

Comment: I decided to remove the \section stuff and adding the enumerate environment. The problem is that when writing in first item, the columns try to balance each other. How can I make when using \newpage it jumps to write in second column?

Comment: @Oshnaj This would be a good separate question, if you can make a simple example document. But first look at the questions on this site about the various multicolumn packages.

Answer (score 8):

I left numerous comments in the code below highlighting bad code, however this version runs without error in latex and pdflatex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% never load epsfig it is just for emulating latex2.09 documents from 1980's
% rotating might be needed for sideways table, otherwise not
% psfrag doesn't work as is with pdflatex or dvipdfm
% graphics is loaded later
%\usepackage{rotating,graphics,psfrag,epsfig}


\usepackage{graphicx}

% color loaded later
%\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}


%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{multicol}

%%% this is loaded later with different options
%\usepackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\newcommand{\ff}{Marzo del 2007}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

%\usepackage[thickspace]{SIunits}

\usepackage[a]{esvect}

% no idea what this is, not in texlive
%\usepackage{shortlst}

\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\newcommand{\solucion}{\noindent\textbf{Soluci\'on}}
\newcommand{\comentario}{\noindent\textbf{Comentario}}
\newcommand{\nota}{\noindent\textbf{Nota}:}
\newcommand{\suge}{\noindent\textbf{Sugerencia}:}
\newcommand{\analisis}{\noindent\textbf{An\'alisis}}
\newcommand{\modelo}{\noindent\textbf{Modelo}}


\fancyhead[L]{} 
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{} 
%
% don't use math \sim
\fancyfoot[L]{\url{http://fisica.usach.cl/~cesparza/}}
%\fancyfoot[C]{\ff} 
\fancyfoot[C]{} 
\fancyfoot[R]{TeoIngMat-EXA1s11.pdf -- 15 noviembre 2011}

\headwidth 18.0cm
\textwidth 18.0cm %18.0cm
\textheight 25.00cm % era25
\oddsidemargin -0.8cm
\evensidemargin -0.8cm
\topmargin -3.5000cm %era  -2.0cm
\columnsep 0.3cm

% I left this but having \parindent and \parskip both 0pt
% means that paragraph breaks  are not really visible
\parindent 0pt

\newcommand{\ia}{\'{\i}}

% The  \rm never did anything here and both
% \rm and \bf have been deprecated since 1994
%\newcommand{\xu}{\rm {\widehat{\bf{x}}}}
%\newcommand{\yu}{\rm {\widehat{\bf{y}}}}
%\newcommand{\zu}{\rm {\widehat{\bf{z}}}}
\newcommand{\xu}{\widehat{\mathbf{x}}}
\newcommand{\yu}{\widehat{\mathbf{y}}}
\newcommand{\zu}{\widehat{\mathbf{z}}}

\newcommand{\iu}{\mathbf{\hat{\imath}}}
\newcommand{\ju}{\mathbf{\hat{\jmath}}}
\newcommand{\ku}{\mathbf{\hat{\kappa}}}
\newcommand{\kuw}{\mathbf{\widehat{\kappa}}}



%\usepackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{ 
pdfauthor = Carlos Esparza Barrera, 
pdftitle = TeoF1-IngMat-EXA1s11.pdf, 
pdfsubject = 2red, 
pdfkeywords =carlos.esparza@usach.cl, 
pdfcreator = {LaTeX con la paqueteria hyperref }, 
pdfproducer = {dvpdfm} 
}



\usepackage{type1cm} 
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{color} 


\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00ED}{\'{\i}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F3}{\'{o}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E1}{\'{a}}

\begin{document}



% psfrag doesn't work with pdf backends
% \psfrag{xu}{$\widehat{\bf{x}}$}
% \psfrag{yu}{$\widehat{\bf{y}}$}
%\psfrag{iu}{$\mathbf{\hat \imath}$}
% \psfrag{ju}{$\mathbf{\hat \jmath}$} 
% \psfrag{i}{$\hat \imath$}
% \psfrag{j}{$\hat \jmath$}

\textbf{Departamento de Fisica \hfill Universidad de Santiago de Chile} 

Teoria a Física I (22104)\hfill \textbf{EXAMEN} \hfill Ingeniería Matemática \vspace{0.1cm}

%\hline is only used in tables
%\hline \hline 
\vspace{0.2cm}

Prof. Carlos H. Esparza-Barrera \hfill \begin{LARGE} \raisebox{-0.5ex}{\Email}                               
           \end{LARGE}  ~carlos.esparza@usach.cl \hfill \begin{LARGE}\Telefon \end{LARGE} ~(56-2-)7181239
\hfill Oficina 27 

% never end a paragraph with \\
%\\[0.1cm] 

%\hline
\begin{itemize}

\item  \begin{large} \textbf{Esta prueba
consta de cuatro problemas, usted debe responder tres de ellos. La
elección es suya y debe indicarla en la hoja. Si responde los cuatro, se considerarán los tres
peor evaluados}
%Always include a paragraph end _within_ a size change this blank line is needed

\end{large}.  \hfill  Cada problema vale $2,0$ puntos. 

\item Fundamente su razonamiento; haga esquemas explicatorios. Use
l\'apiz  indeleble; en caso contrario, no puede pretender una segunda revisi\'on de su trabajo. Exprese sus
repuestas numéricas con 3 CS.


\item Las situaciones y los valores num\'ericos de los datos suministrados no necesariamente corresponden a
los de un experimento o situaci\'on pr\'actica real.  Se pretende que usted  trabaje cada problema  con
el modelo adecuado en el marco de la  teor\'ia  pertinente y obtenga las predicciones correspondientes. 

\end{itemize}
%\hline

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}


\item problema 1

\item ...

\item ...


\item ...


\item ...


\item ...
\end{enumerate}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you say why fontenc before inputenc?

Comment: If you do it the wrong way around, 90% of the 't's don't get deleted when you print, do they?

Comment: [In answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97318/), Ulrike Fischer says that the order does not matter. But that answer is from 2 years ago, so maybe `inputenc` no longer contains the special protections he mentions there?

Comment: @cfr  actually it doesn't make any difference as inputenc delays checks to begin document. But for utf8 (unlike other input encodings) it bases the characters it defines on the known font encodings (from fontenc) to avoid defining the whole of unicode.

Comment: OK. Good. Thanks. It would be inconvenient to have to change the order, so I'm glad there is no reason to.

Comment: @cfr maybe things are changed but inputenc in case of utf8 does not delay action to at begin document. What it does is to take into account already declared fontenc encodings, and it modifies a macro used by fontenc so that if fontenc is loaded later it will do the right thing (i.e. executes the suitable `.dfu` files). Independently of fontenc loaded or not, inputenc+utf8 will execute `\cdp@list` whose default always mentions OML, T1, OT1, OMX, OMS, U.

Comment: @jfbu The problem is probably to do with a combination of print driver and printer memory. At least, that's my theory at the moment. I have workarounds, so it isn't terrible - just have to be careful.

Comment: @cfr which problem? I missed something...

Comment: @jfbu http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241452/generating-a-template/241479?noredirect=1#comment574256_241479 I was trying to solve an extremely frustrating problem in which a PDF which looks fine on screen prints with 90% of serif lowercase `t`s missing. Sometimes it is something else, but this time it was `t`s. I'd printed over 1,000 pages like this. I was trying to find any hint at all of anything I might have done to cause this, including things I thought I knew were fine.

Answer (score 1):

I show that plain TeX code is more straightforward than LaTeX. To create your exam document we can do the following:

```
\input opmac

{\mubytein=0 
 \mubyte\revquestion ¿\endmubyte \gdef\revquestion{?`}
}
\let\secfont=\seccfont  
\font\mvfont=umvs at12pt 
\def\mvchr#1{{\mvfont\char#1}}
\def\Email{\mvchr{107}}  \def\Telefon{\mvchr{84}}
\def\u{\,\rm}

\line{\bf Departamento de Fisica \hfil Universidad de Santiago de Chile}
\line{Teoría a Física I (22104)\hfil {\bf EXAMEN}\hfil 
      Ingeniería Matemática\strut}
\hrule \kern1.5pt \hrule \medskip
\line{Prof. Carlos H. Esparza-Barrera\hfil 
      \lower.5ex\hbox{\Email} carlos.esparza@usach.cl\hfil
      {\Telefon} (56-2-)7181239\hfil Oficina 27\strut}
\medskip \hrule
\bigskip

\begitems \style x \parskip=\medskipamount
* {\typosize[12/14]\bf Esta prueba consta de cuatro problemas, 
  usted debe responder tres de ellos. La elección es suya y debe
  indicarla en la hoja. Si responde los cuatro, se considerarán 
  los tres peor evaluados.\par}
* Fundamente su razonamiento; haga esquemas explicatorios. Use
  lápiz  indeleble; en caso contrario, no puede pretender una segunda
  revisión de su trabajo. Exprese sus
  repuestas numéricas con 3 CS.
* Las situaciones y los valores numéricos de los datos suministrados no   
  necesariamente corresponden a los de un experimento o situación práctica   
  real. Se pretende que usted trabaje cada problema con el modelo 
  adecuado en el marco de la teoría pertinente y obtenga las predicciones
  correspondientes.
\enditems

\hrule\bigskip

\begmulti 2

\sec Insectos


Algunos coleópteros pueden proyectarse verticalmente por sí mismos con una
aceleración de unos $400{\u g}$ (ésto es, un orden de magnitud superior de
lo que un ser humano con entrenamiento puede resistir). El impulso proviene 
en algunos casos de desdoblar sus patas y en otros de curvar violentamente 
el abdomen, hecho que origina un recorrido vertical durante la aceleración 
de unos 0,5{\u cm}. Bajo las anteriores consideraciones:

\begitems \style n
* ¿A qué altura pueden saltar?
* ¿Cuánto tiempo permanecen en el aire?
\enditems

\sec Dos bloques

Un bloque de masa $m= 30{\u kg}$ desliza con aceleración horizontal
$a_{\u m}= 3{\u m/s^2}$ por la parte superior de otro bloque de masa
$M= 30{\u kg}$ por la acción de una fuerza horizontal de magnitud   
$F= 160{\u N}$, como se indica en la Figura.

El bloque de masa $M$ está sobre una superficie horizontal sin roce. Entre
los bloques
$m$ y $M$ hay roce.
\begitems \style n 
* Determine el coeficiente de roce cinético entre los bloques.
* Determine la aceleración del bloque $M$ durante el tiempo que $m$ está
  completamente en contacto con $M$.
\enditems

\endmulti
\bye
```

The result is:

[image: examen]

You can try to preocess this by `pdfcsplain document`. The `pdfcsplain` format is recommended here in order to right interpretation of UTF-8 codes such as ó, í, á. The reversed question mark can be declared in `csplain` by `\mubyte` primitive (see the third line in the code).