# Enumerate and multicol

Tags: multicol

Following up the thread here: [Generating a template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241452/generating-a-template)

and the answer provided by Andrew Cashner, my question now is: I decided to remove the `\section` stuff and adding the enumerate environment. The problem is that when writing in first item, the columns try to balance each other. How can I make when using `\newpage` it jumps to write in second column?

Comment: `\columnbreak`?

Comment: Nice, pretty simple.