# Load order of babel vs. font packages

Tags: fonts, packages, babel, newtx

This question stems from something I stumbled across in the [`newtx` package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/newtx/doc/newtxdoc.pdf):

> ### 2 Text mode options
>
> …
>
> If you use the babel package, you should load it before newtxtext—for
>   example:
>
> ```
> \usepackage[<babel options>]{babel}
> \usepackage[osf]{newtxtext}
> ```
>
> More generally, the pattern of the preamble should be:
>
> ```
> <encoding options>
> [optional] \usepackage{substitutefont} % so you can change babel's fonts
> [optional] \usepackage[<babel options>]{babel}
> \usepackage[p,osf]{newtxtext}% osf in text, lining figures in math
> [optional] redefine the plain theorem style if necessary
> <other font loading commands>
> \usepackage{newtxmath}
> <substitutefont commands>
> ```

I don’t understand what this section is trying to get at – what does `babel` have to do with fonts?

Moreover, I was under the impression that the recommended package order was as follows:

```
\documentclass{…}

% optional font packages
% \usepackage{<font package>}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{babel}

% further packages

\begin{document}
…
```

See e. g. the [`babel` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf), [`fntguide`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fntguide), or [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241479).

Comment: You're probably misled by the mention of `\substitutefonts`, that's rarely necessary and doesn't directly depend on `babel`. My preferred loading order is `fontenc`, `babel` and fonts. I see no reason to “redefine the plain theorem style” before loading `newtxmath`.

Comment: @egreg Indeed I am, especially the comment `% so you can change babel's fonts`. As far as I understand, there’s no such thing as “babel’s fonts”. Also, before reading that paragraph, I had never heard of the `substitutefont` package (and I’m still not sure what its purpose is).